# Freezing while loop on hasNext() invocation

Tags: java, debugging, while-loop, iteration, jena

I am encountering some issues with a call to the basic `hasNext()` method.

I don't understand why this is happening. There's a time in the execution where the program is going to go through this while for 3 iterations

```
StmtIterator statementIt = m.listStatements(null, p, obj);
Statement stamt = null;
List<Resource> lres = new ArrayList<Resource>();
while (statementIt.hasNext())
{
    stamt = (Statement)statementIt.next();
    System.out.println("Debugging: " + stamt.getSubject().toString());
    if(!stamt.getSubject().isURIResource())
    {
        break;
    }
    if(!lres.contains((Resource)stamt.getSubject()))
        lres.add((Resource)stamt.getSubject());
    System.out.println("debugging: there will be another iteration: " + statementIt.hasNext());
}
```

And it does go through it 3 times, but then it gets hung when trying to execute the `hasNext()` operation. I have tried to watch the profile of the program via the debug view (I use Eclipse for developing Java) and, while I am no master of this debug tool, I don't find anything relevant to pinpoint the origin of the abnormality.

I am at a loss here, please send help D:

Comment: How do you create your model?

Comment: you're right about the next... deleting my answer... sorry:(

Comment: The model and StmtIterator are obtained from the Jena package. I create an "empty model", read some ontology file and then "load" said ontology onto said model. I don't think the problem has anything to do with this point of the program, though

Comment: How large is the model, and what storage are you using? My first suspicion here is limited memory, so try VisualVM to get an idea what could be going on.

Comment: Ah, this is an ontmodel? If so, that might well explain the pause depending on the reasoner used and the nature of the ontology.

Comment: @user205512 the .rdf file is 55'3 Kb. I originally had it coded in C# and it ran wonderfully but I have been forced to translate it into Java and I have encountered this problem when running. I will try your VisualVM troubleshooting suggestion tomorrow.

This is an OntModel, correct, but I don't see why the reasoner used would have something to do with a pause that shouldn't happen :/

Comment: @Feillen I think that the comment about the OntModel and reasoner is because .hasNext() needs to determine whether there's another element in the iteration.  That could depend on reasoning.  E.g., the reasoner has to perform inference to find out whether there are any more such statements.

Comment: It surely had something to do with the reasoner. Thanks a lot for you help :) I will post the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user205512 and @JoshuaTaylor I was able to locate the problem.

I was using a reasoner that would hang the program looking for more nodes but  never really working on it (default Jena package implements an interface for Reasoners but no working reasoner).

Solution: either abstain from using a reasoner (not quite the point when working with ontologies) or get a proper reasoner and get it to work (I am currently trying to tame the Pellet reasoner :P )